# HDMI output from FPGA

Tags: audio, fpga, hdmi, ntsc

I've got an old project that produces NTSC video output from an FPGA using a resistor ladder DAC. It also produces a stereo audio signal using a similar RL DAC.

I'd like to bring it into the modern era and produce HDMI output, including audio and video.

So my questions:

1. I see the Spartan-6 has TMDS outputs that can be used for HDMI. Is that the newest FPGA family that can do this? I can't tell if the Spartan-7 does this, or if the line has been renamed since AMD bought out Xilinx.
2. Are there any development boards or reference designs that do this? (Doesn't have to be Spartan-6, I'll look at anything that gets the job done.)
3. Are there any other ways to do this that I haven't thought of?

(I have seen a few similar older questions here, most of which have broken links to external web sites, I'm looking for more up-to-date information. Also, some answers fail because they don't include a solution for audio.)

Comment: I've seen people consume and man-in-the middle HDMI on Zynq72xx based boards, if that helps. I don't know the concrete board name.

Comment: Having worked with one recently (though not for anything video-related), i'm pretty sure I saw stuff about TMDS in the datasheet for the spartan 7 series.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1 I have no answer.

For Q2, likely yes, as mentioned in the comments.

For Q3, of course. You can just generate parallel video out and I2S audio bus for PCM, and buy a HDMI transmitter IC which takes in the video and audio and outputs them over HDMI.

But obviously NTSC is not a native format or resolution over HDMI. You need to generate digital RGB or YCbCr component video at some specific resolution, be it 480i or some other standard format, preferably something all TVs support.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1 the [7 Series FPGAs SelectIO Resources User Guide](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ug471_7Series_SelectIO) has:

[image]

Which shows that in the 7 series FPGA a `HR` I/O bank type with a V<sub>CCO</sub> of 3.3 V is required for TMDS.

The [7 Series FPGAs Data Sheet: Overview](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ds180_7Series_Overview) can he used to find the number of HR I/Os for each 7 series member. E.g. for Spartan :

[image]

For Q2 you could use [Audio Video and Broadcast Boards and Kits](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/market/nav-audio-video-and-broadcast.html) on the Xilinx website and search for `HDMI`. At the time of answering a search for `HDMI` finds 51 results.